# Modify a List's class members without knowing the names

Tags: java, list, class

**What I want** My title may be unclear but I have a program where a user can create students (with name, age, and program). From the Main() the user is prompted with questions and can view current students, and add new students. I'd like to add the option to modify existing students, but I don't know how to refer to them after they have been created.

**What I have**
Here I create the empty list:

```
public static List<Student> populate(){
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    return students;    
}
```

The main calls this method when the user wants to add students, in a loop.

```
public static void addStudents(List<Student >students){
    int Answer = 1;
    while ( Answer == 1){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        //not shown: user enters student's name (NewName) age (NewAge) and program (NewProgram)

        Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);
        students.add(nextStudent);
        nextStudent.age = NewAge;
        nextStudent.program = NewProgram;   

        System.out.println("Do you want to add another student? Press 1 for yes and 2 for no.");
        Answer = reader.nextInt();

    }
}
```

**What I know**

I know how to change a student's properties when I know the name. For example, right when I create a student  and add his age for example, I write
`nextStudent.age = NewAge;`
However since after populating my list they were all called `NextStudent`, I am not sure how to choose a particular student and change their properties anymore.

Comment: `students.get(<some int in the range 0..students.size()-1>).age = NewAge;`

Comment: What do you mean by "However since after populating my list they were all called NextStudent"? It's possible that the error is in how you're asking for the name. Also note that you should move the Scanner construction outside the loop - and now would be a good time to start following Java naming conventions.

Comment: Maintain a map with the name being the key (`Map<String, Student>`) and select them by name.

Comment: @Andy Turner .get would work I suppose, but how is the user supposed to know which student is which int? Should I simply have all the students be named with the integer next to them?

Comment: Iterate through the list looking for a `Student` instance with a particular name.

Comment: Ah I see that's logical. It wouldn't be a good method for long lists though, I suppose a map would be much faster.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to write a method which will return a student object from the list that matches name(or anything else) e.g.

```
public Student findByName(List<Student> students, String name){
    for(Student student : students){
        if(student.getName().equals(name)){
            return student;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once this is done, you can call this method from let's say `editStudent()` method and if it returns an `object` (i.e. `not null`), you can do `student.setName("")`, that would change the name.
If it returns null then you can just display a message saying 'No student found with that name'.

Comment: While this will work, traversing the list every time to retrieve a particular student is algorithmically inefficient. For this simple case of needing to retrieve by name you could use a HashMap<String, Student> instead of a list, for more complicated scenarios you could maintain separate indexes for fast student retrieval. (Although once you want to start persisting your student data you can probably delegate that task to your data storage layer, be it a proper database or some other solution)

Comment: This is *not* how you should do this in a real world application.  There is no reason not to use a `Map` instead, which potentially cuts down search time to O(1) time.

Comment: I suggested this solution assuming that the name will be provided by user. Now, it may not match case, it may have a space in the beginning or end, which will make map key implementation useless. Also, having a method like this enables us to perform smart search on name (or any other property).

Comment: `Map<String, String> nodeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: How about having a space in the beginning or end?

Comment: @DarshanMehta [String.trim();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())